# Ссылка на источник при цитировании

Tags: источники

Представим, что все источники оговорены в списке литературы, каждый из них пронумерован. В тексте используется соответствующее число в квадратных скобках для того или иного источника. К примеру,

1. Розенталь Д. Э. Верный друг учителя-словесника // Русский язык в школе. — 1975

"Здесь идет какая-то цитата из книги Розенталя" [1].

Вопрос заключается в следующем: нужно ли точку ставить сразу после цитаты и до квадратных скобок или все же после квадратных скобок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После квадратных скобок.
Привожку пример из учебника для филологов.

Во-первых, вводится новый термин «нормы речи» («речевые нормы»), который объединяет известные вам понятия: из русского языка – языковой нормы и из стилистики – стилевой нормы. Во-вторых, в этом учебном пособии будет предложена и рассмотрена третья норма речи – эстетическая [3].

Comment: спасибо, я тоже склонялся к этому варианту